# methods.myMethod.call not return value I wanted

Tags: web3js

I am attempt to get an address using methods.call(). And it's something error.

JS

```js
var rcAddr = "0x683d1602fa7252d49cda8ac414c1641a56e73d03";
var methodName = "Access Control";
var register = new web3.eth.Contract(rcAbi, rcAddr);
var accAddr = register.methods.getContractAddr(methodName).call({
    from: "0x70f99451d9878055ca8986021ca78f6edb8f1720",
    gas: 10000000
});
console.log(accAddr)
```

solidity

```js
 function getContractAddr(string memory _methodName) public view returns (address _scAddress){
        bytes32 key = stringToBytes32(_methodName);
        _scAddress = lookupTable[key].scAddress;
    }
}
```

I think I can get a address from function, but it's wrong. So I use `console.log(accAddr)` output the result.

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

It return something else. I'm confused. `methods.myMethod.call` in [document](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12) say

> Returns
>   Promise returns Mixed: The return value(s) of the smart contract method. If it returns a single value, it’s returned as is. If it has multiple return values they are returned as an object with properties and indices:

So It should return the value but why not.

Comment: As the documentation says, it returns a `Promise`, which will resolve when the call completes. Depending on where you're running this code, you can probably use `await`, or you can call `.then` on the `Promise`. (If none of that makes sense to you, search for a tutorial on promises or async/await in JavaScript. This concept isn't specific to Ethereum/web3.js.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing the comment, you may want to try this:

```
async function func() {
    var rcAddr = "0x683d1602fa7252d49cda8ac414c1641a56e73d03";
    var methodName = "Access Control";
    var register = new web3.eth.Contract(rcAbi, rcAddr);
    var accAddr = await register.methods.getContractAddr(methodName).call({
        from: "0x70f99451d9878055ca8986021ca78f6edb8f1720",
        gas: 10000000
    });
    console.log(accAddr);
}

func(); // must be the last line
```